# Cpp Class Constructor no errors?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, buffer

Trying to make a rall class constructor to manage a buffer of two bytes. I was provided a template to work with and was told to add the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, and move-assignment operator correctly. It cant run with any double frees or memory issues in general. Visual studio claims that there's no issues, but running the code gives me an error. What have I done wrong? I have been ***staring*** at my monitor for hours to no avail.

***EDIT:*** sorry, did not clarify what build errors were displayed. Doubt it is something with the IDE. Errors C2338 (static_assert failed, invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution) and (static_assert failed, note: char, unsigned char, unsigned char, char8_t, int8_t and uint8_t are not allowed). and 8 error C2084 lines saying that pretty much all functions already have a body..... very confused.

```
    // buffer.h

#pragma once

#include <typeinfo>

#include <ostream>

constexpr size_t NBYTES = 2;

class Buffer16
{

public:
    Buffer16();

    Buffer16(const Buffer16& other);

    Buffer16(Buffer16&& other);

    ~Buffer16();

    Buffer16& operator=(const Buffer16& other);

    Buffer16& operator=(Buffer16&& other);

    uint8_t *getData() const;

private:
    uint8_t *m_data = nullptr;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Buffer16 &buffer);

    // buffer.cpp

#include "buffer.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

#include <random>

Buffer16::Buffer16()

    : m_data{new uint8_t[NBYTES]}
{

    static std::mt19937 rand{std::random_device{}()};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> dist{0, UINT8_MAX};

    m_data[0] = dist(rand);
    m_data[1] = dist(rand);

    std::cout << *this << "\n";
}

Buffer16::Buffer16(const Buffer16& other)
    : m_data{new uint8_t[NBYTES]}
{
    std::copy(other.m_data, other.m_data + NBYTES, m_data);
}

Buffer16::Buffer16(Buffer16&& other)
    : m_data{other.m_data}
{
    other.m_data = nullptr;
}

Buffer16::~Buffer16()
{

    delete[] m_data;

    std::cout << *this << "\n";
}

uint8_t *Buffer16::getData() const { return m_data; }

Buffer16& Buffer16::operator=(const Buffer16& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = new uint8_t[NBYTES];
        std::copy(other.m_data, other.m_data + NBYTES, m_data);
    }
    return *this;
}

Buffer16& Buffer16::operator=(Buffer16&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = other.m_data;
        other.m_data = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Buffer16 &buffer)
{

    out << "Buffer: [";

    if (buffer.getData() != nullptr)
    {

        out << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << +buffer.getData()[0] << std::hex << std::setfill('e') << std::setw(2) << +buffer.getData()[1];
    }

    out << "] @" << std::hex << &buffer;

    return out;
}

    // main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "buffer.h"

void useBuffer(Buffer16 buffer)
{
}

int main()
{

    Buffer16 b1;

    useBuffer(b1);

    Buffer16 b2;

    useBuffer(std::move(b2));

    Buffer16 b3;

    Buffer16 b4;

    b3 = b4;

    Buffer16 b5;

    Buffer16 b6;

    b5 = std::move(b6);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Buffer: [54, 06] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [00, 00] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [82, c0] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [00, 00] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [e5, bc] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [80, 90] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [99, 38] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [33, 93] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [10, c7] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [30, c7] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [f0, c6] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
Buffer: [d0, c6] @ 0x7ffe344dd438
```

Comment: *but running the code gives me an error.* -- You didn't state what the error is.

Comment: This line is very suspicious: `static std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> dist{ 0, UINT8_MAX };`. MSVC won't compile it and - at best - it is undefined behaviour. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry for no clarification. Post is edited

Comment: Your destructor is clearly bugged since you print out the contents of the buffer after you have deleted it.